# Why parallelStream() starts at specific point most of the times?

Tags: java, java-stream, parallelstream

I have following code which prints elements of a list using parallel stream:

```
List<Integer> l = List.of(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    l.parallelStream().forEach(i->System.out.print(i+" "));
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
6 5 2 8 4 3 9 7 0 1 
6 5 8 9 2 7 4 1 0 3 
6 5 8 9 7 2 4 3 0 1 
6 5 8 9 7 1 0 4 3 2 
6 5 1 0 4 3 2 9 7 8
```

Why the parallel stream starts at `6` most of the times?
 Why not start at `0`? Why not at mid?

Comment: how many cpu cores do you have?

Comment: That's just how race conditions sometimes work out. --- Why would you expect "mid"? Do you believe it only does 2 threads? If it only split the list into 2 chunks, then `0,1,2,3,4` would always come out in that order, given that a thread would be processing a sublist in order. The fact the e.g. `0,1` is sometimes `1,0` would indicate that the two values are printed by different threads, i.e. that code is likely running 10 threads. You could print the thread name to see for yourself how many threads are used: `forEach(i->System.out.print(i+"("+Thread.currentThread().getName()+") "))`

Comment: @Arthurofos `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` returns 4. @Andreas I think the list is being split such that it starts with 6 most of the times. May be because of spliterator?